# How to Remove 3 dots from Thead of Mui Data Grid?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OcMwX.png)
I need to remove this extra feature from data grid Mui. I've tried the root way also. But it's not working for me.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

`disableColumnMenu` prop passed to `DataGrid` component will hide column menu icon (3 dots):

```
      <DataGrid
        disableColumnMenu
        {...other props}
      />
```